# How do I use a node.js script located in S3 with a Cloudwatch synthetics canary?

Tags: node.js, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a Cloudwatch Canary working with an embedded node.js script, but would like the node script to live in S3, then have the lambda just refer to that script. The wish is to export some of the Cloudformation parameters (HostName, Path, and Port) and pass them as inputs into the node.js script to use.

I have tried following the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries_Create.html) on canaries for this, but am still getting an error :

INFO: error.toString() and error.stack.toString(): Error: Cannot find module '/opt/nodejs/node_modules/exports' Stack: Error: Cannot find module '/opt/nodejs/node_modules/exports'

My Cloudformation template is here:

```
Parameters:
  CanaryName:
    Type: String
    Default: my-canary
    MaxLength: 21
  HostName:
    Type: String
    Default: api.net
    MaxLength: 128
  Path:
    Type: String
    Default: /v1/status
    MaxLength: 256
  Port:
    Type: Number
    Default: 443

Resources:
  CloudWatchSyntheticsRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName:
        Fn::Sub: CloudWatchSyntheticsRole-${CanaryName}-${AWS::Region}
      Description: CloudWatch Synthetics lambda execution role for running canaries
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Condition: {}

  RolePermissions:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      Roles:
        - Ref: CloudWatchSyntheticsRole
      PolicyName:
        Fn::Sub: CloudWatchSyntheticsPolicy-${CanaryName}-${AWS::Region}
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - s3:PutObject
              - s3:GetBucketLocation
              - s3:GetObject
              - s3:GetObjectVersion
            Resource:
              - Fn::Sub: arn:aws:s3:::${ResultsBucket}/*
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - logs:CreateLogStream
              - logs:PutLogEvents
              - logs:CreateLogGroup
            Resource:
              - Fn::Sub: arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda/cwsyn-test-*
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - s3:ListAllMyBuckets
            Resource: '*'
          - Effect: Allow
            Resource: '*'
            Action: cloudwatch:PutMetricData
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                cloudwatch:namespace: CloudWatchSynthetics
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - ssm:getParameter
            Resource: "*"

  ResultsBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName:
        Fn::Sub: cw-syn-results-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: AES256

  Canary:
    Type: AWS::Synthetics::Canary
    Properties:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: ${CanaryName}
      Code:
        Handler: exports.handler
        S3Bucket: canary-source-code-ACCOUNT-us-east-1 
        S3Key: exports.zip
      ExecutionRoleArn:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - CloudWatchSyntheticsRole
          - Arn
      RuntimeVersion: syn-nodejs-2.0
      RunConfig:
        TimeoutInSeconds: 60
      ArtifactS3Location:
        Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - s3://
            - Ref: ResultsBucket
      StartCanaryAfterCreation: True
      Schedule:
        Expression: rate(5 minutes) # every minute
        DurationInSeconds: 0 # run indefinitely
      SuccessRetentionPeriod: 5
      FailureRetentionPeriod: 30

Outputs:
  CanaryRoleArn:
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt:
        - CloudWatchSyntheticsRole
        - Arn
  ResultsBucketArn:
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt:
        - ResultsBucket
        - Arn
  ResultsBucketName:
    Value:
      Ref: ResultsBucket
```

My Node script code is here:

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const parameterStore = new AWS.SSM()

// Read SSM

AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1'
})

const getParam = param => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    parameterStore.getParameter({
      Name: param,
      WithDecryption: true

    }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          return rej(err)
        }
        return res(data)
    })
  })
}

module.exports.get = async (event, context) => {
  const param = await getParam(param)
  console.log(param);
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(param)
  };
};

var synthetics = require('Synthetics');
const log = require('SyntheticsLogger');
const https = require('https');

const apiCanaryBlueprint = async function () {
    const postData = "";

    var tempsecret = await getParam('token')
    const secret = tempsecret.Parameter.Value

    var temphostname = await getParam('hostname')
    const hostname = temphostname.Parameter.Value

    var temppath = await getParam('path')
    const path = temppath.Parameter.Value

    var tempport = await getParam('port')
    const port = tempport.Parameter.Value

    const verifyRequest = async function (requestOption) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        log.info("Making request with options: " + JSON.stringify(requestOption));
        let req
          req = https.request(requestOption);

        req.on('response', (res) => {
          log.info(`Status Code: ${res.statusCode}`)
          log.info(`Response Headers: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`)

          // If the response status code is not a 2xx success code
          if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode > 299) {
             reject("Failed: " + requestOption.path);
          }
          res.on('data', (d) => {
            log.info("Response: " + d);
          });
          res.on('end', () => {
            resolve();
          })
        });

        req.on('error', (error) => {
          reject(error);
        });

        if (postData) {
          req.write(postData);
        }
        req.end();
      });
    }
    const headers = { "Authorization" : secret}
    headers['User-Agent'] = [synthetics.getCanaryUserAgentString(), headers['User-Agent']].join(' ');
    const requestOptions = { "hostname" : hostname, "method" : "GET", "path" : path, "port" : port }
    requestOptions['headers'] = headers;
    await verifyRequest(requestOptions);
};

exports.handler = async () => {
    return await apiCanaryBlueprint();
};
```

I read that the file must be in .zip format and must agree with the handler name, in this case, exports.handler, as I have above. I am new to this part of CloudWatch, so I could use a little guidance as to what might be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you haven't placed the file in this structure
exports.zip
└ nodejs/node_modules/apiCanaryBlueprint.js

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?